# Core Data validation: from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, core-data, swift

I'm building a dummy iOS project in order to understand how to implement validation in Core Data with Swift. The Core Data model of the project has one entity called `Person` that contains two attributes: `firstName` and `lastName`. The project is based on Swift but, in order to start it, I'm using Objective-C to define the `NSManagedObject` subclass:

**Person.h**

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

**Person.m**

```
@implementation Person

@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;    

-(BOOL)validateFirstName:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
    if (*ioValue == nil || [*ioValue isEqualToString: @""]) {
        if (outError != NULL) {
            NSString *errorStr = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"First name can't be empty", @"Person", @"validation: first name error");
            NSDictionary *userInfoDict = @{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : errorStr };
            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"Domain" code: 101 userInfo: userInfoDict];
            *outError = error;
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**Person-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "Person.h"
```

In the Core Data Model Editor, I've set the entity class inside the Data Model Inspector as indicated:

```
class: Person
```

The first time I launch the project, I create an instance of `Person` in the `AppDelegate` `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method with the following code:

```
if !NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isNotInitialLoad") {
    let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as Person
    person.firstName = "John"
    person.lastName = "Doe"

    var error: NSError?
    if !managedObjectContext!.save(&error) {
        println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isNotInitialLoad")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

The project has one `UIViewController` with the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var person: Person!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Fetch the Person object
        var error: NSError?
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
        let array = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error:&error)
        if array == nil {
            println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
        person = array![0] as Person
    }

    @IBAction func changeFirstName(sender: AnyObject) {
        //Generate a random firstName
        let array = ["John", "Jimmy", "James", "Johnny", ""]
        person.firstName = array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(5)))]

        var error: NSError?
        if !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
            println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            return
        }

        //If success, display the new person's name
        println("\(person.firstName)" + " " + "\(person.lastName)")
    }

}
```

`changeFirstName:` is linked to a `UIButton`. Therefore, whenever I click on this button, a new `String` is randomly generated and assigned to `person.firstName`. If this new `String` is empty, `validateFirstName:error:` generates a `NSError` and the save operation fails.

This works great but, in order to have a pure Swift project, I've decided to delete `Person.h`, `Person.m` and `Person-Bridging-Header.h` and to replace them with a single Swift file:

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var firstName: String
    @NSManaged var lastName: String

    func validateFirstName(ioValue: AnyObject, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {
        if ioValue as? String == "" {
            if error != nil {
                let myBundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
                let errorString = myBundle.localizedStringForKey("First name can't be empty", value: "validation: first name error", table: "Person")
                let userInfo = NSMutableDictionary()
                userInfo[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = errorString
                userInfo[NSValidationObjectErrorKey] = self
                var validationError = NSError(domain: "Domain", code: NSManagedObjectValidationError, userInfo: userInfo)
                error.memory = validationError
            }
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

In the Core Data Model Editor, I've also changed the entity class inside the Data Model Inspector as indicated:

```
class: Person.Person //<Project name>.Person
```

The problem now is that the project crashes whenever I call `changeFirstName:`. The weirdest thing is that if I put a breakpoint inside `validateFirstName:`, I can see that this method is never called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you are bridging Objective-C and Swift for this. Why not just do it all in Swift? I have had several issues myself bridging the 2 languages, so usually try my best to avoid bridging in scenarios like these

Comment: @AdamM: As I understand the question, it is exactly about "doing it all in Swift". OP wants to replace the Objective-C code by a pure Swift implementation.

Comment: Ahh, I did a quick scan of the code samples and skimmed over that part. My mistake!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a little bit guessing here, but the `(id *)ioValue` parameter is mapped to Swift as

```
ioValue: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>
```

therefore the Swift variant should probably look like

```
func validateFirstName(ioValue: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {
    if let firstName = ioValue.memory as? String {
        if firstName == "" {
            // firstName is empty string
            // ...
        }
    } else {
        // firstName is nil (or not a String)
        // ...
    }
    return true
}
```

Update for **Swift 2:**

```
func validateFirstName(ioValue: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws {
    guard let firstName = ioValue.memory as? String where firstName != ""  else {
        // firstName is nil, empty, or not a String
        let errorString = "First name can't be empty"
        let userDict = [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorString ]
        throw NSError(domain: "domain", code: NSManagedObjectValidationError, userInfo: userDict)
    }
    // firstName is a non-empty string
}
```

As @SantaClaus correctly noticed, the validation function must now
throw an error if the validation fails.

Comment: Note that in Swift 2, these methods should return nothing and instead should throw an error (using error handling in swift 2).

Comment: @SantaClaus: You are completely right, thanks for the notice!

Comment: Really helpful, thanks. The Swift 2 version might be more readable using `guard` as opposed to the if-else with an empty if statement.

Comment: *Very important*: as of iOS 11 you need to declare your class with `@objcMembers class YourClass` order for `validate<Key>` to get called... At least thats what I did to get the framework to call my validate functions.

Comment: @netigger: You are right (but I *think* that it depends on the Swift version, not on the iOS Version. Swift 4 requires to declare Objective-C visibility explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html) is now updated for Swift 3. Here's the example code from the *Managing Object Life Cycle > Object Validation* page (`memory` has been renamed to `pointee`):

```
func validateAge(value: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>!) throws {
    if value == nil {
        return
    }

    let valueNumber = value!.pointee as! NSNumber
    if valueNumber.floatValue > 0.0 {
        return
    }
    let errorStr = NSLocalizedString("Age must be greater than zero", tableName: "Employee", comment: "validation: zero age error")
    let userInfoDict = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorStr]
    let error = NSError(domain: "EMPLOYEE_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 1123, userInfo: userInfoDict)
    throw error
}
```

---

**EDIT:** The example is not quite right. To get it to work, I've changed `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>` to an unwrapped optional and `value?.pointee` to `value.pointee`.

Comment: Would you be so kind to put an example using the "unwrapped optional" you mentioned to use it in Swift 3?

Comment: Don't know why, but my validation method never gets called. Is it enough to put the method validate<field name>? or should it be validate<text field name>?