# Implementing Core Data validation methods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

How do I implement the Core Data validation methods (these take the form `validate<Key>:error:` in Obj-C) in Swift?

In Obj-C, I would write the following in my model class to validate the *name* attribute:

```
-(BOOL)validateName:(id *)name error:(NSError **)outError {

}
```

And I could cast the name to NSString by doing: `((NSString *)(*name))`

In Swift, I assume this looks something like:

```
func validateName(name: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {
}
```

Is this the correct form?

How do I cast then the name to Swift's String?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core Data validation: from Objective-C to Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913310/core-data-validation-from-objective-c-to-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on this is very sparse and there isn't much information about it around the web. Adding here as reference for others what I was able to find via some digging and trail and error.

This seems to be working:

```
// Validating the 'name' attribute of NSManagedObject's descendant
func validateName(name: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {

    if let name = name.memory as? String {
        // do validation here when name is not nil
    } else {
        // when name is nil
        return false
    } 
}
```

Comment: How do I call `validateName()`? I can't seem to coerce the string to type `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>`.